# Creating txt file with certain text and variables from other txt file

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line

Hi i want populate a txt file with words from another txt file.

Example:

I have this txt file source.txt

```
hi hello
my name is 
nice to meet you
```

And this txt file names.txt

```
Dave
Jane
Tom
Jill
```

Want you ask for batch or command line to create final.txt with

```
hi hello
my name is Dave
nice to meet you

hi hello
my name is Jane
nice to meet you

hi hello
my name is Tom
nice to meet you

hi hello
my name is Jill
nice to meet you
```

Thank you in advance. Command line or batch file will be nice or if software for windovs exist which can do this.

Comment: i just hope somebody will by willing to help me because of my nonexistent code typing abilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::  you can set full file paths to the resource files
set "source=source.txt"
set "names=names.txt"
set "final=final.txt"

break>"%final%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%names%") do (
    set counter=0
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("%source%") do (
        set /a counter=counter+1
        if !counter! neq 2 (
            (echo(%%#)>>"%final%"
        ) else (
            (echo(%%# %%a)>>"%final%"
        )
    )
    (echo()>>"%final%"

)

endlocal
```